# Interface Builder menus "save" and "save as" disabled

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

in my xcode project, which is based an persistentDocument, the "save" options are not longer choosable. I've checked the connection to first responder. Everything seems right. When I do some work (data entry) and close the app. The app is asking me, if I want to save. But I just can't choose save from the file menu.

Thank you in advance

KD

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself. I had to connect the application object of the interface builder to the files owner as delegate.

KD